# Search bar - Add content Dynamicly with Ajax and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, search

I'm trying to make a search bar which is loading dynamicly content.

However I wish the real content loading start after the user end typing.

I tried this version but it does not work because it does not take into count each event "keyup".

```
let old_search = ""
let search = ""


$("#search_input").on('keyup paste',function(){

    $("#loader_active").show()
    $('#videos').empty()


    let old_search = $("#recherche").val()

    setTimeout(function (){
        search = $("#search_input").val()
        console.log(old_search + ">" + search)
        if (search == old_search){
            console.log("loading")
            start = 0;
            limit = 20;
            load(search, start, limit);
            start += limit;
        }
    }, 1000);

});

function load(search, start=0, limit=20) {

  $("#loader_active").show()

  let form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('search', search);
  form_data.append('start', start);
  form_data.append('limit', limit);


  $.ajax({

    url: "http://website.com/ajax/videos.php",
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'POST',

    success: function (data) {
      $(data).each(function(index, value) {
        showVideo(value) // show video creates divs with jquery     containing the data from the json received by the ajax call
      })
      $("#loader_active").hide()

    }
  })
}
```

Does any body know any solution ?

Comment: How do you specify the end of a search query ? You mean after 1s ? Can you explain what's happening with your code... We see that between "KeyUps" a delayed query is possible here. So before answering the question, we better understand the expected results. The load function here is handling the ajax call.. how ?

Comment: I would like the search request to be send only after the user did not type anything for 1 second in the search input. I add the load function in order to be easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to make your function reset a trigger that will fire after x amount of time.  Something like:

```js
function myCoolFunction(myParameters) {
    //Clear the timeout every time this happens
    clearTimeout(window.myTimeout);

    //Create a new timeout
    window.myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        //Do Something after 1 second
    }, 1000);
}

$(".selector").on('keyup paste', function (){
  myCoolFunction(myParameters);
});
```

This will execute 1 second after the last 'keyup/paste'. :D